# Запятая перед как

Tags: как, пунктуация

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему в предложении поставлена запятая: *Как поэт, Тютчев сформируется именно в Германии к концу 1820-х годов.* (Может, потому, что оборот с *как* находится в начале предложения, но ведь здесь значение "в качестве".)

Нужна ли запятая в следующих предложениях с *как*:

1) *Эти передачи выводят нас как артистов на новый уровень*. *Как врач я согласен с вами* и *Я как врач согласен с вами.* (Влияет ли на постановку запятой с оборотом *как* его местоположение в предложении?)

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. *Как поэт, Тютчев сформируется именно в Германии к концу 1820-х годов.* - Согласна, запятой не нужно. Это ошибка, видимо, аналогия с причинным значением возникла из-за начального положения оборота.
2. *Эти передачи выводят нас как артистов на новый уровень.* - Тоже "в качестве", но возможно и  как пояснение с причинным значением, но это будет уже авторское.
3. *Как врач я согласен с вами.* - Смысл может быть разным: и "в качестве" (*как врач согласен, а как человек - нет*), и с причинным значением (*Так как я врач, я согласен с вами*).
   Это есть и  во втором случае. *Я как врач согласен с вами.* - Смысловое ударение на обороте *как врач* - в качестве врача - нет запятой. *Я, как врач, согласен с вами*. - причинное значение.

Comment: Пример с Тютчевым взяла из учебника Литература,10 класс. Спасибо за ответы, принимаю все.

Comment: Я в курсе, это Коровин. К сожалению, такое бывает. С учеников требуют строгого соблюдения правил, а сами даже тексты диктантов из области присылают с ошибками. Что поделаешь...время такое.К счастью, я уже не работаю...

Comment: Да, раньше учебники и литература была образцом, по ним можно было учиться, а не по правилам.А сейчас... и в правилах можно запутаться, одни утверждают одно, другие- другое.

Answer (score 3):

КАК ПОЭТ

Правильно: Как поэт Тютчев сформируется именно в Германии к концу 1820-х годов (значение в качестве). Сравнить: Как поэт, Тютчев очень точно выражал чувства и переживания своего лирического героя (значение причины).

Другие примеры: Как поэт, он считал своим долгом быть влюблённым во всех хорошеньких женщин. Как поэт он начался и сложился задолго до нее. Как поэт он постепенно совершенствовался. Некрасов слабо показан как поэт.

КАК ВРАЧ

1) Оборот «как врач»  со значением тождества обычно имеет  значение «в качестве», когда речь идет о мнении (или действии)  врача, которое противопоставлено мнению просто человека  (не обособляется, позиция может быть разная):  Я с тобой сейчас как врач говорю. Но я должен вам не только как врач, но и как гражданин сказать.

2) Если речь идет о действии в соответствии с должностью врача (так как я являюсь врачом), то оборот со значением тождества приобретает причинное значение (обособляется): Я, как врач этой больницы, не согласен с постановлением. Я, как врач, не могу не одобрить этой затеи. Как врач, он должен был немедленно прийти на помощь. Как врач, я разбираюсь в этом.

3)  Иногда можно встретит сравнительный оборот (обособляется): Как будто он, как врач, назначал ей режим.

4) Вот еще интересный пример: Я, как врач и как человек, искренне соболезную Вам. Здесь значение в качестве, но распространенный оборот обособляется, так как  занимает удобную для обособления позицию. Сравнить: Я искренне соболезную Вам как врач и как человек.

Comment: Спасибо огромное.