# "Как" в значении "в качестве" в предложении с инверсией

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Предложение:

> С опытом же, как врач, начинаешь видеть характерные симптомы.

Тут у "как" значение "в качестве". Но оно переставлено: должно быть "начинаешь видеть как врач". В таком случае может быть обособление? Вставка как бы без урона для смысла вынимается из предложения ("С опытом начинаешь видеть..."), поэтому теоретически может обособляться. Но согласно значению самого слова "как" здесь обособления не должно быть. Что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятые нужны.

Розенталь:
Сравнительный оборот может содержать в себе оттенок причинного значения:
*Я, как офицер и дворянин, ни в какую службу к Пугачеву вступить не могу* (Пушкин).
*Васенда, как человек положительный и практический, нашел невыгодным закрепленное место...* (Помяловский).
*Лермонтов близок и дорог, как первый обличитель дворянства* (Маяковский).
*Пятый съезд Советов потребовал установления в Красной Армии железной воинской дисциплины, как необходимого условия ее боеспособности.*
*Был отклонен, как неудачный, проект реорганизации научно-исследовательского института, не предусматривавший тесную связь с производством.
*Она была, как меньшая, любимица отца* (Толстой).
*Как старший, приказываю вам, господа, немедленно разойтись* (Куприн).

Можно заметить, что в таких случаях оборот как бы вклинивается в структуру предложения. Без дополнительных ударений (и запятых) данное предложение не читается. Розенталь предлагает подставлять слово *будучи*:
*С Опытом же, будучи врачОм, начинаешь видеть характерные симптОмы.* || Ударение падает на оборот.

Разница:
*Как врАч вам говорю. || Ударение падает только на оборот.

Как врАч, я вам скажу слЕдующее.* || Два ударения (только с первым не получается).

Comment: Рекомендую ещё прочитать ответ Vera здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/49243

Comment: Ой! Поправьте — _врачЁм._

Comment: Спс, исправлено.

Answer (score 4):

Нашёл следующее неоднозначное правило.

> *Светлане, как лучшему работнику месяца, выдали премию.*
>
> Если в предложении улавливается значение «причины», то есть из одной
>   части можно составить вопрос, а из другой ответ, — выделяем оборот
>   с «как» запятыми. Здесь, конечно, несложно спутать со значением
>   «в качестве», поэтому нужно задавать вопрос: Почему Светлане выдали
>   премию? — Как лучшему работнику месяца. «Джон, как истинный англичан,
>   не попрощался перед уходом» — почему Джон не попрощался перед уходом?
>   Как истинный англичанин. «Алина, как ученица 10 класса, знает всю
>   школьную систему изнутри». Почему Алина знает всю школьную систему
>   изнутри? Потому что является ученицей 10 класса.
>
> Конечно, в этих случаях мы можем толковать смысл предложений
>   по-разному, и решает судьбу запятых непосредственно автор текста.

А в Вашем случае запятые напрашиваются ещё и благодаря структуре предложения.

Вот ещё примеры из Розенталя:

> Сравнительный оборот может содержать в себе оттенок причинного значения: Васенда, как человек положительный и практический, нашёл невыгодным закреплённое место (Пом.) — ‘будучи человеком положительным’; Она была, как меньшая, любимица отца (Л. Т.) — ‘поскольку она была меньшая’; Как старший, приказываю вам, господа, немедленно разойтись (Купр.); Он отбросил это мимолётное подозрение, как внушённое его мнительностью; Освободить, как не справившегося с работой…

Comment: Я голосую за ваш ответ, потому что считаю его полезным. Также я считаю, что это мог бы сделать и автор вопроса. Свой ответ, не имеющий для автора никакой пользы, я удаляю.

Comment: В то же время мне хотелось бы, чтобы он сохранился. Поэтому я задаю по этой теме специальный вопрос https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458404/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%9A-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F