# Оборот с союзом КАК: причина или «в качестве»? Существует ли общая схема решения?

Tags: обороты-с-как

Сколько раз на форуме задавались подобные вопросы, сколько было ответов – и не сосчитать! Но ничего не меняется, а **результат всегда один**: **частным образом** вроде бы решается (или не решается) частная задача **для конкретного посетителя.**

А существует ли **общая схема решения подобных задач**?

Я сама дам первый ответ, чтобы предложить такое общее решение (с целью хотя бы немного сократить поток  вопросов на эту тему).

А как думаете вы? Нужно ли каждый раз предлагать индивидуальный (оригинальный) анализ  для конкретного предложения или можно руководствоваться общими принципами?

Какой план решения (в самом общем виде) используете вы?

Answer (score 1):

Различить эти значения действительно бывает непросто: **семантика, структура, интонация** – какой из факторов является основным?  Или всё нужно учитывать, но тогда каков план действия?

Решение

1. Самое важное – **это смысл, причем всегда.**
2. **Автор предложения знает**, причина здесь или «в качестве». И он выбирает структуру предложения (целенаправленно или интуитивно), чтобы по возможности это обозначить. Если оборот имеет причинное значение, то он обособляется. Поэтому  автору важно выбрать для оборота такую (инверсированную) позицию, где  обособление требуется однозначно, где  он плохо вписывается в основное предложение. Поэтому структура (и соответственно, интонация)  предложения – это **готовое авторское решение** (своеобразная подсказка читателю), поэтому по значимости она сравнивается со смыслом.
3. **Читатель видит** обособленный оборот и понимает, что здесь значение причины. Ему-то особо напрягаться не надо (и даже противопоказано).
4. **А что делает корректор, редактор, учитель в школе** и т.д. Они проверяют и объясняют. У них самая сложная задача: угадать, что думал автор, и проверить корректность выбранной им формы на соответствие этому смыслу.

Для этих специалистов важно **не смешивать** все факторы в единое пространство, а проводить анализ смысла и формы раздельно. А потом сравнить полученные решения.  **И убедиться в их непротиворечивости.**

**Пример решения.** Материал взят  из вопроса ["Как" в значении "в качестве" в предложении с инверсией](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458362/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9)

***С опытом же, как врач, начинаешь видеть характерные симптомы.***

**1. Анализ содержания**
Обратим внимание на пару глаголов: ***смотреть и видеть***.

Конечно,   существует особая (профессиональная) точка зрения врача на окружающую действительность. Обычные люди воспринимают мир несколько иначе. И даже на характерные симптомы (насморка, например) можно СМОТРЕТЬ и как врач, и как обыкновенный человек, то есть по-разному.

А вот ВИДЕТЬ некоторые симптомы может только врач, имеющий опыт, обычный-то человек вообще ничего не увидит. Это уже не точка зрения врача, а умение хорошего специалиста УВИДЕТЬ то, что не видят другие.

Об этом и речь в предложении: я вижу это, потому что я опытный врач. Это значение **причины**.

2. **Анализ формы**

*С Опытом же, как врАч, начинаешь вИдеть характерные симптОмы.*

Инверсия, которую использует автор текста, как раз и подсказывает нам причинное значение, так как структура предложения явно требует обособления оборота.

Примеры **для сравнения** (значение «в качестве»):

(1) *С опытом же **как врач** начинаешь видеть характерные симптомы.*

А неопытный врач как их видит? Как обычный человек, не врач?  Нет, это **неправильно.**

(2) *Обращайте внимание на подобные симптомы. Я **как врАч** вам это совЕтую.*   А вот это правильно.

3. **Вывод**

Оборот ***как врач***  в данной теме может иметь два смысловых варианта:

(1) вижу характерные симптомы как врач (особенным образом, это значение "в качестве")

(2) я вижу эти симптомы вообще, так как я опытный врач (это значение причины).

И в заданном предложении  оборот имеет значение именно **причины**.  По структуре же это соответствует **инверсированной** позиции оборота.

Соответственно, оборот **обособляется.**